# i'm implementing a discord bot to give roles on my reaction to a certain message

Tags: python, discord

i'm implementing a bot discord to gives to users roles when they are reacting to a certain message with specific emoji
but it's isnt adding roles when i react

## This example requires the 'members' privileged intents

```
import discord


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.role_message_id = 1060179348356866119  # ID of the message that can be reacted to to add/remove a role.
        self.emoji_to_role = {
            discord.PartialEmoji(name=':white_check_mark:'): 1060127733151170590,  # ID of the role associated with unicode emoji '✅'.
            discord.PartialEmoji(name=':green_circle:'): 1060127733151170590,  # ID of the role associated with unicode emoji ':green_circle: '.
            discord.PartialEmoji(name='green', id=0): 1060127733151170590,  # ID of the role associated with a partial emoji's ID.
        }

    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
        print("CAZZI NU CGAUSHDUQEWGRIQGH")
        """Gives a role based on a reaction emoji."""
        # Make sure that the message the user is reacting to is the one we care about.
        if payload.message_id != self.role_message_id:
            return
        print("messaggio giusto")

        guild = self.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        if guild is None:
            # Check if we're still in the guild and it's cached.
            return
        print("guild")

        try:
            role_id = self.emoji_to_role[payload.emoji]
        except KeyError:
            # If the emoji isn't the one we care about then exit as well.
            return
        print("role_id")

        role = guild.get_role(role_id)
        if role is None:
            # Make sure the role still exists and is valid.
            return
        print("role")
    
        try:
            # Finally, add the role.
            await payload.member.add_roles(role)
        except discord.HTTPException:
            # If we want to do something in case of errors we'd do it here.
            pass
        print("add role")

    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
        """Removes a role based on a reaction emoji."""
        # Make sure that the message the user is reacting to is the one we care about.
        if payload.message_id != self.role_message_id:
            return
        print("message id")
        #il messaggio è giusto

        guild = self.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        if guild is None:
            # Check if we're still in the guild and it's cached.
            return
        print("guild ok")
        #siamo nella gilda

        try:
            role_id = self.emoji_to_role[payload.emoji]
        except KeyError:
            # If the emoji isn't the one we care about then exit as well.
            return
        print("role error")

        role = guild.get_role(role_id)
        if role is None:
            # Make sure the role still exists and is valid.
            return
        print("role exist error")

        # The payload for `on_raw_reaction_remove` does not provide `.member`
        # so we must get the member ourselves from the payload's `.user_id`.
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        if member is None:
            # Make sure the member still exists and is valid.
            return
        print("member valid")

        try:
            # Finally, remove the role.
            await member.remove_roles(role)
        except discord.HTTPException:
            # If we want to do something in case of errors we'd do it here.
            pass
        print("we do something")


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('....token.....')
```

this is what i get in vsc when i react with :white_check_mark::
message id
guild ok
CAZZI NU CGAUSHDUQEWGRIQGH
messaggio giusto
guild

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your code is failing here:

```py
try:
    role_id = self.emoji_to_role[payload.emoji]
except KeyError:
    # If the emoji isn't the one we care about then exit as well.
    return
```

The `PartialEmoji` in the payload isn't equal to the `PartialEmoji`s you're instantiating in the `self.emoji_to_role` dict. Personally, I would just use the emoji name/str and that should work fine.

ie;

```py
self.emoji_to_role = {
    "✅": 1060127733151170590,
    "": 1060127733151170590,
    "green": 1060127733151170590
}
```

and then later use `payload.emoji.name` to get the role from the dict.
`payload.emoji.name` will be the unicode representation for unicode emojis and whatever name you entered when you created server emoji for customs.

```py
try:
    role_id = self.emoji_to_role[payload.emoji.name]
except KeyError:
    # If the emoji isn't the one we care about then exit as well.
    print(f"Couldn't find role ID for emoji name {payload.emoji.name}")
    return
print(f"Found role ID {role_id} for emoji name {payload.emoji.name}")
```

That should hopefully work a bit better for you. I added some more useful debug too. Didn't test beyond getting the role ID but that seems to be where your issue is.